# Docker - running exe that show dialog/form from powershell file causing the fault

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I have an .exe program that I need to run it in docker at startup. I can run it from powershell of container without any error but not from powershell script file.

- container name : base
- exe file name : abc.exe

.exe runs without any error and as expected :

- `docker-compose ecex base powershell`
- `PS C:\> abc.exe -someParam xyz`

But when I call it from a powershell script file it gives me following error :

**runexe.ps1 file :**

```
# run 
abc.exe -someParam xyz
```

---

**error :**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog 
box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a 
valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to
display a notification from a service application.
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
```

So, how can I overcome this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to run EXE via `Start-Process` powershell cmdlet since it allows you to specify additional parameters relevant how Windows elements are handled.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian thanks, it works!

Comment: Accept my answer below please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` powershell cmdlet to control execution of EXE inside docker build, it allows finer control of process lifetime